# no overload for method 'all' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, abp

i want to get all Procedure codes but i got error "no overload for method 'all' takes 0 arguments" while coun() is working fine

```
private static void Processor()
    {
        IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>();
        IDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver _connectionStringResolver = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver>(); ;
        IDbContextResolver _dbContextResolver = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IDbContextResolver>();
        var srcConnectionString = "Server=NABIIL\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=db-qa; Trusted_Connection=True;"; //ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString("Default");
        var targetConnectionString = "Server=NABIIL\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=db-Migrated; Trusted_Connection=True;";  //ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString("Target");
        DbContext srcContext, targetContext;
        Debugger.Break();
        var procedureCode = "";
        using (srcContext= _dbContextResolver.Resolve<DbContext>(srcConnectionString, null))
        {
            //var items = srcContext.Patients.Count();
            procedureCode = srcContext.ProcedureCodes.All();
            Debugger.Break();

            //_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (targetContext = _dbContextResolver.Resolve<DbContext>(targetConnectionString, null))
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            //var items = targetContext.Patients.Count();
            targetContext.Patients.add(procedureCode);
            //_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think doing just `.All()` should accomplish? `Count` and `All` don't do the same thing, so it's not really useful to compare them like that.

Comment: `All` only returns a bool indicating if all elements in your list satisfy a condition. When you want to return all elements, just use `procedureCode = srcContext.ProcedureCodes`.

Comment: When in doubt [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @HimBromBeere thanks for replying when i use
.All i got exception"the function evaluates all threads to run"

Comment: @HimBromBeere 
my problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to store all items in a list into a variable.

The `All` method is a method that works on a collection. That means that `srcContext.ProcedureCodes` is already the value that you are trying to obtain. (You probably have to call `ToList()` on it still)

`Count` is a method on a list that will count the numbers of items in that list, so `srcContext.ProcedureCodes.Count();` will give you the number of elements in `srcContext.ProcedureCodes`.

`All` is a method that takes an argument, i.e. a function that All applies to all elements of the list. This function must have an argument of the type of the list All works on, and must return a `boolean` value. The method `All` will return `true` itself, if applying the function to all elements in the list also give `true`.

Comment: Great dont forget to close or delete your question